# QGIS Layer field expression in Polymorphic Relation evaluates to NULL

Tags: qgis, relation

In QGIS 3.34.3, according to the [doc](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/joins_relations.html#defining-polymorphic-relations):

> **Layer expression** evaluates to a unique identifier of the layer. This can be the layer name @layer_name, the layer id @layer_id, the layer’s table name decode_uri(@layer, 'table') or anything that can uniquely identifies a layer.

(note: the 'field' word is missing there)

the "Layer field expression" of the Polymorphic  Relation editing window can be set to `@layer_name` or `decode_uri(@layer, 'table')` but both these expressions evaluate to NULL within the Expression Builder:

[image]

In addition, `@layer_name` does not exist in the available elements inside the Expression Builder and the `'table'` value is a handwritten keyword that I don't know what it refers to (it's not explained in the documentation).

Does anyone have some more details on this?